# excludeFromIndexes: [] does not work. entity properties are still indexed

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I have a transaction where I am saving an entity and I have an array excludesFromIndexes.when the entity is saved it shows the properties as indexed even though I added excludefromindexes.

```
  function test(user,pass,array,callback){
        let transaction = ds.transaction();
        let key = ds.key('questions')
        transaction.run()
        .then(()=>
            transaction.save(
                {key: key,
                data:{
                    'user':user,                                                                                                                                     
                    'pass':pass
                },
                excludeFromIndexes:['user','pass']}))
        .then(()=> transaction.commit())
        .then(function(apiResponse){
            callback({response:'successful'});
        })
        .catch(function(err){
                transaction.rollback()
                callback({'error':err});
            })
      }
```

Comment: What version of datastore library for nodejs are you using?

Comment: how do I check ?

Comment: `npm ls -g` should do the trick.

Comment: Updating the library fixed the problem. Thanks

Comment: @A.Queue: you should add an answer to not leave the question unanswered. Yes, it's basic enough for just a comment, but IMHO it could be useful for other users.

Comment: @DanCornilescu Sure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different version of Google Datastore libraries are using different syntax and may ignore excludefromindexes completely.

Updating to the latest version is recommended.